# Difference between 2 numbers in array of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am using mongodb which have following structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a868d785e5436aeed0502c0"),
"symbol" : "ABC",
"values" : [ 
    {
        "High" : 53.0,
        "Close" : 51.85,
        "Open" : 50.8
    }, 
    {
        "High" : 51.35,
        "Close" : 50.25,
        "Open" : 50.35
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to calculate the percentage change of first 2 elements of the close field.

But while calculating the difference 
 collection.values[0].Close - collection.values[1].Close

I am getting pricediff as null.PFB code.

```
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate(
{
 $project:
   {
      symbol:1,
      today: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values.Close", 0 ] },
      yesterday: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values.Close", 1 ] },
      pricediff: {
         $subtract: [ "$today", "$yesterday" ]
     }
 }})
```

And Is there any other way to calculate percentage change of 2 values.

Thanks...J

Comment: When you are calculating the percentage difference; your second reference is incorrect I.e you are calling collection.values[1].close and it should be collection.values[1].Close

Comment: It's just a reference of way how I am doing, corrected that also...Actual mongo DB code is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a single pipeline using **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** and the following arithmetic operators:

```
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "pricediff": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 0] },
                    { "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1] }
                ]
            },
            "precentage_change": {
                "$multiply": [
                    {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1] }, 0] },
                            1,
                            {
                                "$divide": [
                                    {
                                        "$subtract": [
                                            { "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 0] },
                                            { "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1] }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    { "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1] }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    100
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the output is returning only 50 records. Any way to retrieve all the records from collection.

Answer (score 1):

Any new (or renamed) fields can't be used within the current stage but only in later stages.

```js
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate({
  $project: {
    symbol: 1,
    today: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 0]
    },
    yesterday: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 1]
    },
    pricediff: {
      // CAN NOT USE THESE FIELDS AS THEY WERE CREATED IN THIS
      // PROJECTION
      $subtract: ["$today", "$yesterday"]
    }
  }
})
```

Since new fields can not be used in the same projection they are created, you can either use multiple stages or duplicate code to access the fields that you want to compute the values.

#### Using two projection stages:

```js
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate([{
  $project: {
    symbol: 1,
    today: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 0]
    },
    yesterday: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 1]
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    symbol: 1,
    today: 1,
    yesterday: 1
    pricediff: {
      $subtract: ["$today", "$yesterday"]
    }
  }
}
}]);
```

#### Using a single projection stage with [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/):

```js
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate([{
  $project: {
    symbol: 1,
    today: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 0]
    },
    yesterday: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 1]
    },
    pricediff: {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          today: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 0]
          },
          yesterday: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 1]
          }
        },
        in: {
          $subtract: ["$$today", "$$yesterday"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

#### Using a single projection stage (but more concise):

```js
db.getCollection('abc').aggregate([{
  $project: {
    symbol: 1,
    today: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 0]
    },
    yesterday: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 1]
    },
    pricediff: {
      $subtract: [
        { $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 0] },
        { $arrayElemAt: ["$values.Close", 1] }
      ]
    }
  }
}]);
```

The percentage change is simply adding the correct formulae in the same way the difference is calculated.